# Downloaded data is always nil

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6, download

```
FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
friendPicker.fieldsForRequest = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:@"picture", nil];
[friendPicker loadData];
[friendPicker presentModallyFromViewController:self
                                      animated:YES
                                       handler:^(FBViewController *sender, BOOL donePressed) {
                                           if (donePressed) {
NSURL *profilePictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:friend[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"]];
                                                               NSURLRequest *profilePictureURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:profilePictureURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f]; // 
NSLog(profilePictureURL.absoluteString);
                                                               [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:profilePictureURLRequest
                                                                                                  queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                                                                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* receivedData, NSError* error)
                                                                {
                                                                    UIimage *userpic = [UIImage imageWithData:receivedData];
                                                                }];
```

Url is not empty:
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/370130_506171594_768019817_q.jpg

But receivedData is nil — I tried different ways to download data from url.

Can anyone say what's wrong with this code? These code was working, but started to return nil data some time ago.

Comment: Did you check whether you get an error? You have an error parameter in that method, you should use it.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks, I'll do right now

Comment: error is "The Internet connection appears to be offline." Probably it's because https protocol?

Comment: P.S. Internet connection is OK, and FB picker shows contacts.

Comment: I don't have any experience with https, but that could be the problem. You probably need to do something with authentication.